How to do JIT in another AppDomain?
The code is shown below。There are Two DefaultDomain in Process，and i need to do JIT in DefaultDomain, NGEN's AppDomin Can JIT，but another cant.
var Domains = GetAllAppDomains();

foreach (var domain in Domains)
{
    ObjectHandle handle1 = domain.CreateInstanceFrom(
        typeof(Process).Assembly.ManifestModule.FullyQualifiedName,
        typeof(Process).FullName
    );
    Process DomainProcess = (Process)handle.Unwrap();
    var Methods = DomainProcess.GetType().GetRuntimeMethods().ToList();
    var StartWithCreateProcess = Methods.Where(_ => _.Name == "GetCurrentProcess").FirstOrDefault();

    var methodhandle = StartWithCreateProcess.MethodHandle;
    var methodAttr = StartWithCreateProcess.Attributes;
    var methodType = methodhandle.GetType();
    if (!((methodAttr & MethodAttributes.Abstract) == MethodAttributes.Abstract || methodType.ContainsGenericParameters))
    {
        RuntimeHelpers.PrepareMethod(methodhandle);
    }
}

i try to use RuntimeHelpers.PrepareMethod, but it didn't work
Maybe can Call C++ complier to JIT？

Given that in modern .NET you can only have one AppDomain (multiple domains only exist in .NET Framework), why would you be spending time building such a solution in 2024?

"i need to do JIT" why? What do you hope to achieve by pre-empting the JITter?

@Damien_The_Unbeliever Some solution providers may consider creating multiple AppDomains and using them in specific scenarios。such as Financial business

@Charlieface for CodeAddr and monitor

that's why use AppDomain? Application domains - .NET Framework | Microsoft Learn

Note that AppDomains don't work in .NET Core, so you'd be advised to move to a different model of separation as soon as.
